# how do i put two print codes on one line once the code has been run

Tags: python

im making an input equation for schoolwork and right now, and i want to print the equation's answer, followed by "is the circumference" on one line once the code has been run.

[this is what i have right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4T2G5.png)

[this is the outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSfBz.png)

[this is the outcome i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxnKj.png)

Comment: Use [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html). Something like this `"{} is the circumference".format(circumference)`.

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.

Answer (score 0):

this should do the trick or you can also you formatted strings

```
    a = 12
    print(str(a) + " answer")
```